# If I change ID of an element in Android Studio, how do I carry on this change throughout the code?

Tags: android, android-studio

For example, say I'm using a relative layout and a lot of views are centered around a TextView with ID of TextView. If I change this ID to TextView1, the other elements referencing it all break. How can I change the ID so that the changes are carried out?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Typically the first time you perform a change like this it asks if you want it to change all occurrences of the item

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select what you want to refactor

> for windows

Press `Shift+f6` do **refactor**

> for Mac

press `Shift+fn+F6` do **refactor**

Answer (score 1):

You can easily replace all ID's in one step, just press strg+r on windows.

In the first text field put in your old ID and in the second one the new ID, press **Replace all** and you're done.